# Android app crashes without stacktrace on logcat

Tags: android, android-service

I run my app in Android Studio debugger and get "[AppName] keeps stopping", although it doesn't actually stop. It's just an `android.app.Service` that appears to be crashing, yet on LogCat I see no stack trace and putting breakpoints in the Service constructor, for example, it  doesn't stop there either.

Answer (score 0):

Android Services are running in their own processes. When you configure in your Manifest your service

```
    <service
        android:name=".service.SomethingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":Something" />
```

Check logcat for `:Something`. You should find a process called `yourappname:Something`. There you find your stacktrace.

For the debugging part of the question you probably need to add this line:

```
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

where appropriate in your Service' onCreate or so. Then you have time to connect to the process once the server is stuck on that line. Don't forget to remove the line before publishing.

Comment: although this is your own question but since you haven't posted any code in your question, this answer is more like an assumption.

Comment: Well, I lost many hours because I did not assume this and didn't find it suggested anywhere. Thought it should come up for those in a similar situation.

Comment: I am not saying that you shouldn't have posted this but you should have included the service manifest code in the question too

Comment: I did not realize my "logcat was broken" due to service being used. In fact a coworker had introduced Firebase and some necessary step was not run on the service' start, so the changes were not even around service code that broke the app instance from starting.